# PHP getimagesize, Mysql fetch from DB and update field

Tags: php, mysql, sql-update, getimagesize

I've been a lot around this site the last couple of days, and found a lot of useful tips for a newbie to php as I am (this is my second day :) ) Therefore I'll sure hope you gurus can help me finishing this script.

What do I have:
I have this table within my Mysql:

```
------------------------------![Sql Tabels][1]
----------------------
```

**Would should it do:**
The script have to get some table rows where the "diemensions" field is emty `IS NULL`
Now the script have to find the image size and spit it out in this format **width**x**height** the x between the width and height is important.

Where the image is not to be grabt, it should just pass by, and take the next one.

**When it's done:**
It have grabt the image size and updated the "dimensions" field in the DB

**Sources for my code:**
[How to determine the picture size, then selectively insert into the database? php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4183120/how-to-determine-the-picture-size-then-selectively-insert-into-the-database-ph)

[Update MySql Field (if field is not empty, go to next one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11176410/update-mysql-field-if-field-is-not-empty-go-to-next-one)

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php

**The PHP it self**

```
<pre><code>
<?php
    #  first we check, if gd is loaded and supports all needed imagetypes
    function gd_get_info() {
        if (extension_loaded('gd') and
            imagetypes() & IMG_PNG and
            imagetypes() & IMG_GIF and
            imagetypes() & IMG_JPG and
            imagetypes() & IMG_WBMP) {
   
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }


    $username = "";
    $password = "";
    $database = "";
    $db_hostname = "";

    mysql_connect("$db_hostname","$username","$password") or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("$database") or die(mysql_error());

    //check if the starting row variable was passed in the URL or not
    if (!isset($_GET['startrow']) or !is_numeric($_GET['startrow'])) {
      //we give the value of the starting row to 0 because nothing was found in URL
      $startrow = 0;
    //otherwise we take the value from the URL
    } else {
      $startrow = (int)$_GET['startrow'];
    }

    // Retrieve all the data from the "example" table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tx_gallery_previews WHERE dimensions IS     NULL     ORDER BY gallery_id ASC LIMIT $startrow, 10") or die(mysql_error());  

    // store the record of the "example" table into $row
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    //$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 

    $pid = $row['preview_id'];
    $gid = $row['gallery_id'];
    $imgfile = $row['preview_url'];
    $dimens = $row['dimensions'];

    /*
    echo $row['gallery_id'];
    echo $row['preview_url']. "\r\n<br />"; */
    extract($row);
    //print $pid. " ".$imgfile." ";
    //print "".$dimens."<br />";


    $blah = getimagesize("$imgfile");
    $type = $blah['mime'];
    $width = $blah[0];
    $height = $blah[1];

    if (isset($width)) {
    echo  $pid. " ".$imgfile." ".$width. "x".$height. "\n"."<br />";

    mysql_query("UPDATE into tx_gallery_previews         (preview_id,gallery_id,preview_url,dimensions) VALUES          ($pid,$gid,$imgfile,$width."x".$height)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE dimensions=VALUES('"$width."x".$height"')");

    } 
         else{ echo "$pid <img src=\"$imgfile\" width=\"90\">Image not found"."<br />"; }

    }


    // close connection 
    mysql_close($connection);


    $prev = $startrow - 10;

    //only print a "Previous" link if a "Next" was clicked
    if ($prev >= 0)
        echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.$prev.'">Previous</a> ';

    //now this is the link..
    echo '<a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?startrow='.($startrow+10).'">Next</a>';
    ?>
    </pre></code>
```

**Seen but couldn't make it work**
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php
Post by "james dot relyea at zifiniti dot com  07-Feb-2009 08:49"
But seems to be the right ideer for my script.

XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
When you answer this topic, please explane wich part does what.

Best Regards

Joakim